# Get the sObjectType of a field dynamically

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, dynamic-binding

I have a field `Board_Name__c` that is a lookup from Opportunity back to Opportunity.  How can I dynamically find out that `Opportunity.Board_Name__c` references the Opportunity sObject while `Opportunity.Account` references the Account sObject?

Comment: One way to do it would be a soql query to select a row and using the Id.getSObjectType() method on the Id held in each lookup field to get the sObject type.

Comment: Thanks techtrekker, but I'm trying to figure this out when there are no pre-existing relationships.  If I have a not-yet-committed new sObject, I'd like to be able to tell the reference object for a given reference field (no Id is present if the records are not yet committed...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the describe for the Field there's a referenceTo property which indicates which type(s) the foreign key is for, e.g.

`system.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.AccountId.referenceTo[0].getDescribe().getName());`

prints `Account`

The docs have a [section](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) on the describe functionality

Comment: Awesome, that never showed up when I looked up Schema.DescribeFieldResult on Google... Thanks!  Also, I was specifically asking about dynamic apex and how to get it to a string (what you have above returns a List<Schema.SObjectType>:  I have a map (Map<String, Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>>) called mapSObjectFields, and the correct nomenclature from there was:  mapSObjectFields.get(sObjectName).get(relationshipName).getDescribe().referenceTo[0].getDescribe().getName()  I am worried about the double "getDescribe()" required here...  Any better way?

Comment: Salesforce officially got rid of "describe" limits, so this is a non-issue!